# how to start a handler from service after 15 second to prevent app from sleep and send location to webservice?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-gps

I am working on GPS tracking Application in which I need to track location after 15 seconds. I have use handler to start service from onStartCommand() from Service class. but After 15 second or after some time after it handler does not execute always. I have also used WakeLock to prevent app from sleeping. how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Handler inside service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006889/using-handler-inside-service)

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> { ... }, 15000);
```

The action (lambda here) will be executed after the timeout (15,000 ms.)

Expanded it might look like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Track my location
    }
}, 15_000);
```

Comment: I have done this way but  it is not execute always after 15 second

Comment: On what platform - Could this be doze mode?

Comment: in Android Platform

Answer (score -1):

Use `Timer` instead of `Handler` as shown below

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do your task here
            }
        }, 15000);
```

Comment: Exactly why this is such a bad suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339630/984830